# Reverse for 'post_edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$']

Tags: python, django

I am making a blog site but there is an issue:

In my home page, I have blogs which I have added. However
when click them, they are showing a `500 error`
which is stated as : `NoReverseMatch at /post/1/`.

My code body is as follows and my app name is 'Blog':

**Models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

author = models.ForeignKey(
    'auth.User',

    on_delete=models.CASCADE,

)

body = models.TextField()


def __str__(self):
    return self.title


def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**Urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path


from . import views

urlpatterns = [

          path('', views.BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),

          path('post/<int:pk>/', views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

          path('post/new/', views.BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),

          path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
]
```

**Views.py**:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView

from . models import Post



class BlogListView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'home.html'


class BlogDetailView(DetailView):

model = Post

template_name = 'post_detail.html'
context_object_name = 'anything_you_want'    


class BlogCreateView(CreateView):

model = Post

template_name = 'post_new.html'
fields = '__all__' 


class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):

model = Post

fields = ['title', 'body']
template_name = 'post_edit.html'
```

I am using `Import Reverse` to get back on the same page after adding the blog, but it is showing same error too.

Comment: It looks as if the error is coming from the template for `BlogDetailView`, which is `post_detail.html`. It's strange to use `context_object_name = 'anything_you_want'` - that means you would use `{% url 'post_edit' anything_you_want.pk %}`. If you remote that line, then you would use `{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}`, which is easier to understand.

Comment: upload your details.html file also

Answer (score 0):

you should update your post_detail.html template file like following code probably because you set `context_object_name = anything_you_want` of BlogDetailView class in views.py !

```
% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class = "post-entry">
        <h2> {{ anything_you_want.title }} </h2>
        <p> {{ anything_you_want.body }} </p>
    </div>
    <a href ="{% url 'post_edit' anything_you_want.pk %}">+ Edit Blog Post</a>
{% endblock content %}
```